# Parent directory(../../) vs http(s):// links in href includes

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, embedding

What is the difference when using

```
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

rather than using

```
<link href="http://example.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://example.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there any downside?

Comment: not much. they're just two different ways of telling the browser where to go. first one's "relative", and is easy to move between servers/sites as long as the relative pathing stays constant. The other one's global absolute, works everywhere, but breaks if you change the site structure/name.

Comment: Do all browsers versions support relative links or just modern ones?

Comment: other than the "telnet to port 80" browser, it's been in html/http since day 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no downside of using the relative links. There're some downsides of using the full links though:

1. it's longer (obvious!)
2. you'll have to rewrite all such links in case you move your site somewhere else
3. you shouldn't really force to use either http or https

On the other hand, the full link is something you can't escape if you're loading the resource from other domain.

Comment: One downside of using relative links is that if the HTML file is moved to another folder, all the relative links will have to be changed.